# "Inequivalent" or " nonequivalent"?

Tags: academic-writing

How to write correctly: "inequivalent" or " nonequivalent"? I am interested in writting this word in mathematical texts.

Comment: Both words mean exactly the same.

Comment: Could you give a sentence for context, please? 'Mathematical texts' is helpful but more context is better :)

Comment: The best thing to do might be to read other mathematical papers in the same area by established mathematicians, and use whichever term they use

Comment: In one book, I found the phrase: "All these subdivisions give a rather long list of inequivalent possible structures". An example from another book:  "... problem of classification of all nonequivalent systems of basis vectors ...".

Comment: Google Ngram Viewer [shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inequivalent%2Cnonequivalent&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinequivalent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnonequivalent%3B%2Cc0) that *nonequivalent* is twice as common as *inequivalent*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful comments! I've discovered [Google Ngram Viewer!](https://books.google.com/ngrams)